# Implementing Iterable vs implementing Iterator

Tags: java, iterator, iterable

I have an object that I would like to implement custom iteration into, but:

- I do not want to have to create all of the next patterns at once.
- I want it to work in the enhanced for-loops, but I do not want to have to create a secondary `Iterator` object for all the actual iteration, because the iteration requires accessing a private field.
- I want to require a second object being made rather than a second iterator be made.

So my solution was to implement both `Iterator` and `Iterable`, and include the following method in my implementation:

```
@Override
public java.util.Iterator iterator() {
    return this;
}
```

Is this okay practice? If it isn't, what should I do to properly work around this problem?

Comment: An `Iterator` encapsulates some state, most notably for the `hasNext()` and `next()` calls. What happens if someone wants to loop over your object twice?

Comment: With my intentions, I want to require them to make a new object to iterate again.

Comment: Did you know that member classes (including inner classes) can access private fields of the containing class? You can make an inner class that implements Iterator; you don't need to make your private field public for that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is not okay practice.  Create a secondary `Iterator` object, and make that `Iterator` a *nested class* inside your current class, which will permit it to access private fields.

In general, trying to make your object an `Iterable` and an `Iterator` at the same time is extremely likely to confuse users and break code that makes assumptions about how an `Iterable` works, in particular that it can be used more than once.